# How to make this with php a youtube video?

Tags: php, iframe, video, youtube, str-replace

I have some text which is including a video link everytime ffrom youtube but in this form :

Lorem ipsum text e3txt sdfsdds f dsf sdf 
dsfsdfds fds fds fds f dsf sdf sd fds fd
Lorem ipsum sgsdfds fds fds fdsfsdfsdfds.

```
{youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube}
```

...so what i want to do, is that i want with php to make the {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube} a playable video using iframe code as follow :

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uqfYNxP7GzM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem is that uqfYNxP7GzM is not always the same !!! For very video is other.. hm so how i can turn this pattern {youtube}hereeverytimedifferentcode{/youtube} into iframe playable video ?

Maybe with preg-replace, str-replace or some similar function ? But how can i do that since the value into {youtube}value{/youtube} is every time other ?

Thanks n waiting fro your precious help !

Comment: i want to make this {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube} ..into this iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uqfYNxP7GzM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe ..but uqfYNxP7GzM is every time newone not the same, changes ..how ???

Comment: Legionar did you found anything funny ? Can you help on it plz ?

Comment: i guess we need regex too ..right ? but i dont know much about regex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really good at regex. But this may work:

```
$opa2 = " Lorem ipsum text e3txt sdfsdds f dsf sdf dsfsdfds fds fds fds f dsf sdf sd fds fd Lorem ipsum sgsdfds fds fds fdsfsdfsdfds domr text jwweorw {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube}"; 
$pattern = "/{youtube}(.*?){\/youtube}/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $opa2, $matches);
if(isset($matches[0]) && !empty($matches[0])) { // if indeed there are
    $id = reset($matches[1]);
    $opa3 = preg_replace($pattern, "<iframe width='640' height='360' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$id'></iframe>", $opa2);
}
echo $opa3;
```

Comment: Thats very good ! But i have a problem .. the {youtube}{/youtube} things remains in the output.. are shown :( Please see the modified code below :        $pattern = "/{youtube}(.*?){\/youtube}/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $opa2, $matches);
if(isset($matches[0]) && !empty($matches[0])) { // if indeed there are
    $id = reset($matches[1]);
    
}
        
$opa3 = str_replace("$id", "<iframe width='640' height='360' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$id'></iframe>", $opa2);

Comment: @Markets_is_modern_Slavery so `{youtube}{/youtube}` needs to be removed in the string?

Comment: The code here better : http://pastebin.com/HLDDSkiV   the {youtube}here is video showing perfect{/youtube} are show in the output when ill echo $opa3; . I want {youtube}{/youtube} to dont be visible on output. How to do that ?

Comment: preg_replace and $pattern was the solution ! Thanks for your help was very important to me. Thanks a lot man !

Comment: Hm.. i have one more case on the example we solved before.

In the case that {youtube}uFcTAk_A9Nc{/youtube} inside it has some elements and it is like this :

   {youtube}uFcTAk_A9NcuFcTAk_A9Nc |600|450|0{/youtube}

What we can do ?

As you can see, the problem is the extra data included "|600|450|0" this kind of data appears sometimes and can be different too. Ones may be |600|450|0, other time |800|600|0 etc..

So... in this case what we can do in order to resolve it as we did before ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. i have one more case on the example we solved before.

In the case that {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube} inside it has some extra elements and it is like this :

{youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM |600|450|0{/youtube}

What we can do ?

As you can see, the problem is the extra data included "|600|450|0" this kind of data appears sometimes and can be different too. Ones may be |600|450|0, other time |800|600|0 etc..

So... in this case what we can do in order to resolve it as we did before ?

I tried:

```
$pattern1 = "/{youtube}(.*?)600|450|0{\/youtube}/";
```

But is not working..

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's preg_match method with the regex "`/\{youtube\}(.*)\{\/youtube\}/s`". and return the 2nd element of the $array as your result

```
    $input= "{youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube}";

    preg_match("/\{youtube\}(.*)\{\/youtube\}/s",$string, $r);

    $result= $r[1];

    echo $result;
```

Comment: $starttext is in this form including text and the {youtube}value{/youtube} --> $startText = " Lorem ipsum text e3txt sdfsdds f dsf sdf dsfsdfds fds fds fds f dsf sdf sd fds fd Lorem ipsum sgsdfds fds fds fdsfsdfsdfds domr text jwweorw {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube}";

Comment: We dont have to separate firs {youtube}value{/youtube} from the rest of the text that $startText has ?  ..hmm and also the point is to replace {youtube}uqfYNxP7GzM{/youtube}.

Comment: Thanks Lissy but MarioD'Boro understood what i wanted better his answer it was what extactly i wanted to do. Anyway have a look above, your code it helped me too is on the right logic but doesnt fit on my case exatcly.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it a little by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?